# How to generate embeddings using Bert

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, embedding, bert-language-model

I started using the following Kaggle kernel:

- https://www.kaggle.com/taindow/bert-a-fine-tuning-example

After, I have used the following code which is getting close:

```
bert_config = modeling.BertConfig.from_json_file(bert_config_file)

processor = ColaProcessor()
label_list = processor.get_labels()

tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file=vocab_file, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)

tpu_cluster_resolver = None
is_per_host = tf.contrib.tpu.InputPipelineConfig.PER_HOST_V2

train_examples = processor.get_train_examples(data_dir)
num_train_steps = int(len(train_examples) / train_batch_size * num_train_epochs)
num_warmup_steps = int(num_train_steps * warmup_proportion)

print("Feature Test")
features = convert_examples_to_features(examples=train_examples, label_list=label_list, max_seq_length=max_seq_length, tokenizer=tokenizer)
print("Feature Test Completed")
```

After I do this, I get the following output for my `features` variable:

```
 <run_classifier.InputFeatures at 0x7f798eece780>,
 <run_classifier.InputFeatures at 0x7f798eefd7b8>,
 <run_classifier.InputFeatures at 0x7f798eece5c0>,
 <run_classifier.InputFeatures at 0x7f798eecec18>,
 <run_classifier.InputFeatures at 0x7f798eece978>,
 <run_classifier.InputFeatures at 0x7f798eeced68>,
 <run_classifier.InputFeatures at 0x7f798eece208>,
 <run_classifier.InputFeatures at 0x7f798eecea58>,
```

My confusion is how to convert this to an array of embeddings that I can use for other tasks. I could be missing how Bert works.

Comment: Do you want to use bert embedding for classification or do you just want to use bert embeddings in some other task or DNN architecture?